# How to convert dateTime in the correct ISO string with javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I try to get the dateTIme in this format:

```
"2021-01-27T07:30:00Z"
```

so: yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ

But I get as format like this:

```
2021-01-27T09:48:00.000Z
```

So it seems that there is a extra double 00 in it.

So I have it now like this:

```
startLineChartDate = new Date();
 this.startLineChartDate.setHours(1,0,0, 0);
const startDate = this.startLineChartDate.toISOString();
```

And I want to start time always on current day with: 00:00:00

But so what I have to change?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert date to ISO String. just use toISOString method. eg;

```js
a = new Date().toISOString();
console.log(a)
```

If you want something else, please mention the format

Comment: So without the 000Z. But in this format: "2021-01-27T09:35:00Z"

Comment: So I want to have in this format: DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")